# Facing error while running my Servlet application on apache tomcat 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

“I have defined welcome file list in servlet program. still my application is not loading the same at the time of startup.what can be the reason? Note that i have put that html file inside web inf folder.”

I have rebuilt and redeploy my application. still it doesn't working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>VoterApp</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>wert</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>VoterServ</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>wert</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/voterSite</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

It should load index.html on startup when i run my web application VoterApp but i am getting resource not available error.

Comment: web.xml in WEB-INF and html/jsp in root or relative path and VoterServ in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: yes , my VoterServ is in WEB-INF/classes folder. may i know where to place html file as currently i have placed it in WEB-INF folder. @pks

Comment: root folder outside WEB-INF as it should be in root already(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWb8X.png)
--index.html
--META-INF
       //
--WEB-INF
      web.xml
      --classess
              //

Comment: performed same as above but still not getting the desired output. @pks

Comment: i have placed my welcome file directly under VoterApp and that's why i am not getting desired output. thanks for A2A. @ pks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to move your index.html file outside of the WEB-INF folder, in the root directory.

```
rootFolder
 |-- WEB-INF
 |    `-- web.xml
 `-- index.html
```

It should work.